# Pass an instance to another class and access it c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm simply passing a pointer to an instance of a class to another class but I just can't access anything from the pointer. It's really, really starting to bug me. Here's a really simple example of the code:

```
//manager.h
Game* game = new Game();
BClass* bc = new BClass(this);

//bclass.h
BClass(Manager* bcref) {
    bcref->game //error
    bcref->bc //error
}
//The errors are "left of ->x must point to class/struct/union/generic type.
```

I understand this is because I need to forward declare but adding things such as "class Manager;" at the top doesn't seem to do anything. I still can't access a member or method. I'm really trying to do something that's incredibly simple and I've been pulling my hair out for hours. I've googled and tried pretty much everything I can.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to do this:

```
BClass* bc = new BClass(this);
```

`Manager` needs the definition of `BClass`. This is presumably in `bclass.h`. In order to do this

```
bcref->game;
```

`BClass` needs the definition of `Manager`. This is presumably in `manager.h`.

So you would need include each header in the other, which would lead to a cyclic include dependency. What you really need to do is break the dependency by moving the implementations to `bclass.cpp` and `manager.cpp` respectively, and use only forward declarations in your headers.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting me onto the right track! I can't believe I spent over 6 hours (pathetic I know) trying to get this working and it turns out it was basically because I needed both header and cpp files.